# how to enable nebula widgets in designer's palette of Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, widget, palette

I've just configured Eclipse Indigo(for RCP) in Ubuntu 11 and everything is fine with it as compared to  my previous IDE Eclipse Helios(for RCP) except one thing : that is I installed all nebula widgets from their installation repo : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/nebula/snapshot and http://download.eclipse.org/technology/nebula/incubation/snapshot. I can access all widgets in palette of Design view. But there is neither any widgets of nebula nor the category nebula in palette.I had installed all nebula widgets from above repos and made Eclipse clean restart, several times; yet the problem persists. How can I enable nebula widgets in my Eclipse Indigo IDE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Problem has been solved: All we need to do to enable nebula widgets in our Eciplse Indigo Design-View's(window-Builder) palette is: putting the respective nebula widget's jar file into our project's class-path from previous Eclipse-helios IDE's plugin folder; and switching into design-view; then nebula widgets are available there under group 'nebula' as in previous Eclipse Helios IDE.That's all.

Comment: Hi, How do i do this in Eclipse Juno?