# How to install SWT_XYGraph_2.1.0 widget into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, widget, swt

I searched Google, but did not see how to add a widgit, like [SWT_XYGraph_2.1.0](http://code.google.com/p/swt-xy-graph/), to Eclipse, such that when I go to the SWT designer view, I see the control in the palette.

I saw articles that said to import a jar, do " | Build Path | Configure Build Path... | Add External Jars...", however that does not add the widget to the palette.

I also saw articles that talked of copying the features and plugin files to the appropriate eclipse folder, but I do not see any feature files. What I see is:

```
org.csstudio.swt.widgets.source_2.1.0.201209121549.jar
org.csstudio.swt.widgets_2.1.0.201209121549.jar
org.csstudio.swt.xygraph.source_2.1.0.201209121540.jar
org.csstudio.swt.xygraph_2.1.0.201209121540.jar
```

What is the step-by-step guide on how I can import the SWT widgit into Eclipse and see the widget.

Note, I already added the 49.jar widgit file using 'Configure Build Path', although I guess that I can remove it just as easily.

Also, do I place the widget files into the

I am running Eclipse on Windows, but app needs to work on CENTOS Linux as well.

Eclipse Standard/SDK
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

I am using WindowBuilder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible. What makes you think that you can see custom widgets in the "Palette"? (I'm assuming you mean a plugin like WindowBuilder)...

Comment: These are just Eclipse plugins so you could just add them to your Target Platform (or your Eclipse install if you don't have one). As Baz says I doubt that WindowBuilder will recognize them but they can be used 'by hand'. Also note that the web site clearly says they are obsolete and Eclipse Nebula should be used instead.

Comment: Yes, I am using WindowsBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that Eclipse Nebula is the new version. I missed that small text, even though it was at the top of the home page.

Comment: I found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781333/how-to-enable-nebula-widgets-in-designers-palette-of-eclipse-indigo, however I did not have much luck. I installed the software using the update site, no issues. I then copied the content of the features and plugin folder to the respective eclipse folder, restarted, and still nothing. I am not sure what jar to add to the class path, as there are a zillion.

Comment: If I go to "palette | Add component...", I do see "Nebula" as a category, just I do not see "Nebula" as a category in the palette, so it looks like I have to enable/add Nebula to my project to see it, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for WindowBuilder: [Custom Composites & Panels](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/index.html). It allows you to add *any* Composite subclass (I assume XYGraph is one; if it's a Canvas subclass instead, wrapping it in a Composite should be simple).